# Unable to create a new Ionic project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic7

Every time when I try to create a new ionic angular project using `ionic start`, it triggers an error in the console.

**Error:**

> Network connectivity error occurred, are you offline? 
>  If you are behind a firewall and need to configure proxy settings, see: https://ion.link/cli-proxy-docs 
>  Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.example.com at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:108:26)

I tried to configure the proxy using the [ionic rules](https://ion.link/cli-proxy-docs). But the error persists.
I also tried to research the error on the internet, but I don't find anything much different than ionic docs.

I also tried to change my WI-FI, because when I attempted to create this app, I was at the university using the public campus internet, so I thought this problem was happening because of the public WI-FI, but I also tried in my home and the error persists. I already have developed ionic apps, but always in version 6 or below. I don't understand much about proxy and network matters and, don't have much time to research. So, please, if you could help me, that would be great.

**Update**
I tried to disabled Windows Firewall, but doen'st work too.

Ionic: v7.1.1 
Npm: v9.8.1 
Node: v18.17.0

Thanks in advancement!

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by doing the following:

1. `ionic config unset proxy --global`
2. `ionic config get proxy --global`

This will unset any bad proxy configuration in `C:\Users\your-user\.ionic`

You can see more information about this [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/using-a-proxy) and [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ionic-cli-cant-login/170515)